# Moved my Codeigniter project to another server to get a blank screen

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Now, I'm not exactly and expert in PHP, but my CMS i've created is going very well on my local server. I've attempted to place it on a live server to get blank page outputs everywhere except from when i use Codeigniters 'welcome' controller. Now i've checked every single file and i don't have one page that i close the PHP tags like so `?>` when the page is completely PHP.

So is there a way that white space could be doing this another way apart from white space after tags?

Does white space after php tags between HTML tags count?

I've tested my database configuration and it works perfectly, so i don't know what else it could be. Just getting fed up of looking for something i'm completely not sure about and getting no where.

EDIT: You can see my lovely whiteboard here: http://asphaltcms.com/

**EDIT:** I can 100% confirm that preset/new controllers, models and views are working so it's something wrong with my current controllers ect, can white space appear in more than just after and before `<?php ?>` tags?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: check for error messages in the server log and / or enable error display.

Comment: Server log gives no errors and the error display is enabled, and error reporting is on. And there's nothing.

Comment: do you need to include `index.php` in your URL? ie. `example.com/index.php/controller/method` vs. `example.com/controller/method` - if the first works & the second doesn't, it's a URL rewrite problem.

Comment: Make sure you `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` in `index.php` and set `$config['log_threshold'] = 2;` in `application/config/config.php`, then check `application/logs` for new error messages. Also check your Apache/nginx/lighttpd configuration.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with it?
DEBUG - 2014-04-24 20:13:37 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2014-04-24 20:13:37 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-04-24 20:13:37 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-04-24 20:13:37 --> No URI present. Default controller set.

Comment: Note: that happens when i load the homepage on the server (blank screen)

Comment: are you using .htaccess

Comment: I am my .htaccess contains the following:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: I can 100% confirm that preset/new controllers, models and views are working so it's something wrong with my current controllers ect, can white space appear in more than just after and before <?php ?> tags?

Answer (score 1):

I'll recomended to check following points if you are getting white screen ,

1:Check logs (PHP,Apache both)

2:Compare PHP info with your local code to live.

3:Check if **short_open_tag** is on or not

4:Enable error in config file.(error_reporting(E_ALL);

I hope this would help you to get rid of white board :)

Comment: No log errors when comparing, PHP info is very similar, error reporting is on and I've used no short tags :/

Comment: So my local server: PHP Version 5.4.25
Live Server: PHP Version 5.4.26

Comment: It's not only about PHP version , I meant to say the PHP modules , make sure nothing missing there.

Comment: They are pretty much the same: unless anything whitebaordy comes across as obvious here:
http://asphaltcms.com/

Comment: I can 100% confirm that preset/new controllers, models and views are working so it's something wrong with my current controllers ect, can white space appear in more than just after and before <?php ?> tags?

Comment: i don't think so. Well i had similar problem in past but i did which i have posted. Did you change your base url in config file?

Answer (score 1):

Well i never figured this out, but my working result was just new codeigniter installation and re writing the code out quickly. Works on 3 web servers without any issues.

I later encountered an issue with .htaccess files being involved but i've resolved that :)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just moved a site to a new host/server and experienced the same issue - White screen and no errors.

I noticed that I didn't have the php module GD or MYSQL installed so I installed those and it fixed my issue.

On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```